# Include ENUM in a new ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: enums, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.8

I've created a new ASP.NET MVC project running on .NET 4.8. I've added classes, controllers, model, interfaces... and it builds properly.

Now I need to create an enum but I'm missing something here. I've created an `App_Code` folder at the root of the project, added `Enum.cs` then I created a new namespace as shown here:

```
namespace ContosoSystem.App_Code
{
    public enum ExpireDate
    {
        SampleExpire = 30,
    }
}
```

In the controller, I can't apply `using ContosoSystem.App_Code` nor `using ContosoSystem`. If I do this, I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'App_Code' does not exist in the namespace 'ContosoSystem' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

At the top left, there is this field mentioning `4_App_Code` (see print below). It was supposed to be my project there, but I can't switch to my project as mentioned at the tooltip. So, it seems that `Enum.cs` is somewhere out of my project.

[image: tool tip at the top left field]

Comment: Why did you name the directory App_Code?

Comment: This project is actually a spin-off of another project, and at the original project the `App_Code` folder exists, therefore the idea is to keep similar structure.

Comment: Yeah but App_Code has a special meaning and is like 20 years old. Try putting your code in another place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed this issue by creating an 'Enum.cs' file in the 'Utils' folder, organized and named as shown below:

```
namespace ContosoSystem.Enum
{
    //Sample
    public enum sampleData
    {
        setting = 10,
    }
}
```

This solution has been working for the past two months. I didn't understand why I couldn't use App_Code as I had originally planned.